# Easy way to separate strings in an array with commas in Rails with and before last string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I have a method to insert commas between strings and have an "and" before the last element:

```
def commas(array)
  return '' if array.length == 0
  return array.first if array.length == 1
  return "#{array[0..-2].join(', ')} and #{array.last}"
end
```

Just curious if there's a Rails or Ruby method to easily achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has a method `to_sentence`:

```
[1,2,3].to_sentence
# => "1, 2, and 3"
```

Comment: Perfect! Stackoverflow won't let me accept the answer for 5 mins. I prefer `[1,2,3].to_sentence(last_word_connector: ' and ')`